# Redshift REGEXP_SUBSTR get last occurrence of a match

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse, regexp-substr, listagg

I have a list of page events of all types in a column value ordered by time asc that I got using listagg method.
`listagg(page,';') within group (order by time)`

I want to get the occurrence of the last match that matches the regex
`regexp_substr(event_list,'/step[0-9]+[^;]*')`

According to the docs "A positive integer that indicates the position within source_string to begin searching. The position is based on the number of characters, not bytes, so that multibyte characters are counted as single characters. The default is 1. If position is less than 1, the search begins at the first character of source_string. If position is greater than the number of characters in source_string, the result is source_string."

Based on this I need to know the exact occurrence number which I do not know. 
How to get the last match in this case?
eg :
`/step1;somethging;somethig;/step2;something;/step3;something;`

I want to match step3.

PS:  Ordering by time desc and getting the first match is not an option here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`regexp_count`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_COUNT.html) to determine how many matches there are (`n`) & then use [`regexp_substr`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) to get the `n`th match.

```
select 
  '/step1;somethging;somethig;/step2;something;/step3;something;' string
, '/step[0-9]+[^;]*' pat
, regexp_count(string, pat) n
, regexp_substr(string, pat, 1, n) last_part
```

outputs:

```
                                                       string                pat    n    last_part
/step1;somethging;somethig;/step2;something;/step3;something;   /step[0-9]+[^;]*    3       /step3
```

*if `/` could be treated as a delimiter, then you may alternatively employ the following strategy*

reverse the string, split by `/` & take the first part. reverse again, prefixing `/` and apply the regular expression to extract the step:

example:

```
select 
  '/step1;somethging;somethig;/step2;something;/step3;something;' string
, '/' || reverse(split_part(reverse(string), '/', 1)) last_part
, regexp_substr(last_part, '/step[0-9]+[^;]*') extract_step
```

outputs:

```
                                                       string           last_part   extract_step 
/step1;somethging;somethig;/step2;something;/step3;something;   /step3;something;         /step3
```